# How to get the list of Meet codes to Google Sheet in Classroom with Google App Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom, google-meet

I have a lot of classes in Classroom that have created Google Meet Links. I want to export a list of all those Google Meet Links to google sheet using google app scripts. Hope you can help. Thank you very much. have a nice day

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search) efforts as is suggested in [ask]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

So far as I know, you can't get the meet code from Google Classroom API. The only way that you can get google meet code is taking it from settings in each Classroom.